# findstr match beginning of line

Tags: regex, batch-file, findstr

I would like extract the Raw Value of a smartctl -a query.
Unfortunately, I can not make the findstr command so that the hit is only at the beginning of the line.

Here is the Example Output from smartctl:

```
C:\>c:\Programme\smartmontools\bin\smartctl.exe -A /dev/hdb
smartctl 6.5 2016-05-07 r4318 [x86_64-w64-mingw32-win8.1] (sf-6.5-1)
Copyright (C) 2002-16, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 10
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
  1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate     0x000f   080   063   044    Pre-fail  Always       -       111886652
  3 Spin_Up_Time            0x0003   097   097   000    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  4 Start_Stop_Count        0x0032   100   100   020    Old_age   Always       -       40
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x0033   100   100   010    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  7 Seek_Error_Rate         0x000f   078   060   030    Pre-fail  Always       -       67217403
  9 Power_On_Hours          0x0032   099   099   000    Old_age   Always       -       1541
 10 Spin_Retry_Count        0x0013   100   100   097    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0032   100   100   020    Old_age   Always       -       13
184 End-to-End_Error        0x0032   100   100   099    Old_age   Always       -       0
187 Reported_Uncorrect      0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
188 Command_Timeout         0x0032   100   099   000    Old_age   Always       -       4295032833
189 High_Fly_Writes         0x003a   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
190 Airflow_Temperature_Cel 0x0022   066   062   045    Old_age   Always       -       34 (Min/Max 28/38)
191 G-Sense_Error_Rate      0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
192 Power-Off_Retract_Count 0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       8
193 Load_Cycle_Count        0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       98
194 Temperature_Celsius     0x0022   034   040   000    Old_age   Always       -       34 (0 11 0 0 0)
195 Hardware_ECC_Recovered  0x001a   051   003   000    Old_age   Always       -       111886652
197 Current_Pending_Sector  0x0012   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
198 Offline_Uncorrectable   0x0010   100   100   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0
199 UDMA_CRC_Error_Count    0x003e   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
```

The Following Code works fine, but i want to search for the ID# Column and not for Attribute_Name:

```
C:\>for /F "tokens=10" %a in ('c:\Programme\smartmontools\bin\smartctl.exe -a /dev/hdb ^| findstr  "Seek_Error_Rate" ') do @echo %a
67221721
```

Thanks for any contribution!

Please excuse my bad english!

Comment: Change `tokens=10` to `Tokens=1`, if you want to return the `ID#` for the searched `ATTRIBUTE_NAME`.

Comment: To search for the `ID#` alone then this is all you need `C:\Programme\smartmontools\bin\smartctl.exe -a /dev/hdb | findstr/bc:"197 "`

Comment: thank you for the hint! For ID 7 this is the right way: findstr /bc:"  7" !   I have not used the blank in the previous attempts!

Comment: `c:\Programme\smartmontools\bin\smartctl.exe -A /dev/hdb | findstr /R /C:"^..[0-9]"` using line position anchor: `^` beginning of line.

Comment: @Daniel, because you appear to have two padded spaces, I'd suggest you use `FindStr/BC:"<space><space>7<space>"`. @JosefZ, your code suffers from the same issue as @aschipfl's answer, it retrieves every line beginning with an `ID#` not one with a specific `ID#`

Comment: So you want to search for one specific `ID#`?

Comment: @Compo my comment suggests to use  _line position anchor_ `^` instead of `/B` switch. Merely another option, not an answer to quite bit vague question. The OP asks _I can not make the findstr command so that the hit is only **at the beginning of the line**_.

Comment: @JosefZ, I understand that and had previously commented on your usage in my now deleted comment. I only mentioned it because it may have accidentally sent aschiflp, (and almost myself), down what appears to be potentially the wrong route too.

Comment: Hello, this is working fine: for /F "tokens=10" %a in ('c:\Programme\smartmontools\bin\smartctl.exe -a /dev/hdb ^| findstr  /BC:"  9" ') do @echo %a    | Sorry again for my english!

Answer (score 0):

What about this:

```cmd
findstr /R /B /C:"[ 0-9][ 0-9][0-9] "
```

This could also match lines beginning with a digit, followed by a space, followed by another digit, but I think such do not occur anyway. If they do, then use this:

```cmd
findstr /R /B /C:" [ 0-9][0-9] " /C:"[0-9][0-9][0-9] "
```

(You can specify multiple search string with `/C`, which are ORed.)

Comment: Whilst your `FindStr` examples are great, they don't answer the question. What you've provided will return every line beginning with an `ID#` not search for a specific `ID#`.

Comment: @Compo, seems I have misunderstood the question; I asked the OP for clarification; as soon as they rely, I am going to update my answer...